# How to set a default text ="search here" placeholder in kendo Grid

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular6, placeholder

[image: This is the code I am using present]
This is the code I am using present, tried in many ways like used placeholder tags but nothing worked out. Help me

```
<kendo-grid-column field="food" title="foods">
<ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
  <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell
      [showOperators]="false"
      [column]="column"
      [filter]="filter">
  </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
```

Comment: What type of kendo are you using? The Angular one?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach working now

Just put this piece of code in your component file

```
public placeHolders(){
            $(".k-textbox").eq(0).attr("placeholder", "column 1");
            $(".k-textbox").eq(1).attr("placeholder", "column 2");
            $(".k-textbox").eq(2).attr("placeholder", "column 3");

}
```

Comment: ugh what an ugly approach to have to change the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to write default placeholder in kendo-UI > kendo-grid-string-filter-cell as per my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you and I cannot find an easy way to do it. The only way i can think to achieve this is below:

1) Create a **Reusable Custom Filter Component** from Kendo -> https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/

2) Then add a **TextArea Input** as your filter input and there's the **floatingLabel**  html element in order to use it like placeholder.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
    <textarea kendoTextArea></textarea>
  </kendo-textbox-container>
`
```

I cannot find a way to do this by using the **Built-In Filter Templates** that Kendo UI provides.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure of your question.  I'm using Vue, but here is how I am setting placeholder text when there are no records by setting the `noRecords` attribute.

```
          <kendo-grid ref="gridComponent"
                  ...

                  :no-records="noRecords"

                  ...
                  v-on:change="rowSelected"
                  :sort="sortFilter">
```

In Vue, `noRecords` is a reactive data field, defined as:

```
  data () {
     return {
        noRecords: {
          template: '<br /><br/> Please start typing a Policy Number, Insured Name, or Address to show results <br /><br /><br />'
        }
     }
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to set placeholder text like "Search here" in my search box, when user trying to search that column that placeholder have clean up by placing cursor in it